# What is it called when applying the solution provided to a particular question / problem creates a new problem?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-usage

What is it called when applying the solution provided to a particular question creates a new problem?

Potentially: "consecutive problem" or "subsequent problem"?

What is this called in plain English?

Comment: I can think of some two-word examples: chain reaction and domino effect.

Comment: See also the adjective *cascading*, as in [cascading failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_failure): most often negatively, as in your example, but also used positively when it creates an amplification effect (*signaling cascade* in Biology, for example)

Comment: That's called "business as usual".

Comment: Please fix your punctuation and spelling.

Comment: @Lambie Please correct my post, if I would know then did not ask question on first place :D and you have enough reputation to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's the...

> *[Law of]* [***unintended consequences***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unintended_consequences)

If that's not "self-explanatory" enough, it's all explained in the linked Wikipedia article.

Comment: no no, this is not I am asking, this is just like *aftermath* thing

Comment: I have seen unintended consequence used in both a positive and negative sense, as explained in the article. If this term were used, context would need to make clear that the unintended consequence in this instance is negative.

Comment: @user770884: I don't generally think much of Wikipedia, but in this case it's misleading to suggest that clarification might be needed, because (1) the "unintended" consequences are *almost always* bad, and (2) in the relatively uncommon cases where they're *serendipitously **good,*** that should be contextually obvious anyway.

Comment: @diEcho: I don't understand your comment. Everything about your question text points to "unintended consequences" being what you're asking for. If that's not what you're looking for, ***please edit your question text*** to give a clearer definition.

Answer (score 1):

Unintended consequences, though generally used in the negative sense, may also apply to a positive. The exclusively negative form of an unintended consequence is sometimes known as the "Cobra Effect," in which the solution to one problem can be directly linked to the emergence of another, potentially higher-magnitude, problem.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perverse_incentive), the Cobra Effect originated as follows:

> The British government, concerned about the number of venomous cobras in Delhi, offered a bounty for every dead cobra. Initially, this was a successful strategy; large numbers of snakes were killed for the reward. Eventually, however, enterprising people began to breed cobras for the income. When the government became aware of this, the reward program was scrapped. When cobra breeders set their now-worthless snakes free, the wild cobra population further increased.

Comment: To expand on this a bit, the Cobra Effect implies that the solution ultimately directly worsens the original problem (c.f. the idiom "the cure is worse than the disease"). It is also a specific example of the general idea of a "perverse incentive".